# multipart/form-data not working on ionic iOS

Tags: ios, http, post, ionic-framework

I have an ionic 3 project that allows for file upload to the server. The following code is working fine from Android. But on iOS it appears to get blocked (i.e. the server code at /upload.php is obviously the same in both cases, but coming from iOS it does not receive any of the posted data).

```
this.http.setDataSerializer('urlencoded');
this.http.post("http://example.com/upload.php", {
  name: this.filename,
  data: this.datafile
}, {"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"})
.then(res => {
  console.log('success response: ' + res.data); 
}, error => {
  console.log(error: ' + error);
});
```

Any ideas?

Is there some setting in xCode that needs to be configured to allow multipart/form-data posts to work? Or perhaps somewhere to white list the domain to allow it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be on the server side. Apparently PHP receives the post differently from Android as it does iOS. $_REQUEST["xxxx"] works fine for Android but in order to work for both it required this:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
parse_str($postdata, $param);

// then available as $param["xxxx"]
```

Thought I'd update the answer here in case anyone else bumps into this. Awfully obscure and took me days to figure out!